# MVC 5 CRUD delete with foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crud

I am currently working on MVC 5 CRUD, and I just started last week. What I am encountering is an error when I use the DELETE on one of my tables because I am deleting a row of data on table A but the primary key of table A is a foreign key of table B.

Is there any way that if I delete the data on table A its corresponding data on table B will be also deleted? Thank you.

Comment: Yes there is and its called a cascading delete

Comment: Okay thank you sir, will try to research on that. But do you have any idea where I can possibly perform that?

Answer (score 1):

The MVC part here is irrelevant, your database design is as such that the DELETE would fail regardless of technique used.

As pointed out above by Chino you should be looking at your database, and specifically the relationships between table A and table B, and set these to cascading delete. Meaning that when a row in table A is deleted, the row in table B is deleted too  (hence 'cascading')

Answer (score 1):

First You Delete foreign key of table B Data And Then A Table.